# modified date assistance

Tags: powershell

I have this piece of code that changes a string if it exist. It works perfectly. However, even if the Server1 string doesn't exist in the file it changes the modified date of the file. What I need it to do is if the string Server1 doesn't exist ignore and move on to the remaining files in the folder.

Does anyone here know how I can go about achieving this?

```
$filenames = Get-ChildItem "C:\test\*.dtsconfig" -Recurse |
             select -Expand FullName

foreach ($filename in $filenames) {
  (Get-Content $filename) -replace 'Server1', 'Server2' | Set-Content $filename
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the file only if it actually contains the string "Server1":

```
$txt = Get-Content $filename
if ($txt -like '*Server1*') {
  $txt -replace 'Server1', 'Server2' | Set-Content $filename
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$fileNames = Get-ChildItem "C:\test\*.dtsconfig" -Recurse | Select -Expand FullName

foreach ($filename in $filenames) {
    $file = Get-Content $fileName   
    If ($file -like "*Server1*") {
        Get-Content $fileName -replace 'Server1', 'Server2' | Set-Content $fileName
    }
}
```

I've added in an if statement so it checks before making any changes.

Comment: This would only work if there is no other text in a line with the word "Server1", which is rather unlikely for *.dtsconfig files.

Comment: Ahh yes very true! I've updated to use the like operator and included wild cards either side of the value.